# Postgres Update multiple JSONB columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a table (postgres 12) with the below schema

```
ID (Int)  | Meta (JSONb)

1   | {"id": 1, "source": "a"}
```

I need to update multiple rows to the below format

```
ID (Int)  | Meta (JSONb)

1   | {"id": "1", "source": "a"}
```

My only options are

1. Fetch all records on my application server. update the struct and then update each row individually by looping within a transaction. (Im using go-sqlx which unfortunately doesnt seem to have support for batch updates)

There are about 3k records I have to update. so this seems inefficient

The other idea i had is to try something like this

```
update
    tbl
set meta = jsonb_set(meta, 'id' , meta ->> 'id'::text)
where meta ->> 'source' = 'a'
```

This unfortunately doesnt seem to work. is there a way for me to get the old column value here -

`jsonb_set(meta, 'id' , "how do i get old json key value here?"::text)`

i get the below error

`function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, text) does not exist....`

What is the best approach here?

**EDIT** based on Edonaurds answer and other threads. I modified the query a bit

```
update
    tbl
set meta = jsonb_set(meta, '{id}', (meta->>'id')::jsonb)
where meta ->> 'Source' = 'a'
```

While this updates - i still cant seem to convert the ID field into string

i still get back the original row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
update
    tbl
set meta = jsonb_set(meta, '{id}' :: text[] , to_jsonb(meta ->> 'id'))
where meta ->> 'source' = 'a'
```

Comment: I seem to be getting a ` function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, text) does not exist` error - i am using postgres 12 though

Comment: answer updated should work

Comment: I get this error now `function jsonb_set(jsonb, text[], text) does not exist` - you have put me on the right track though - i updated my question

Comment: your updated query seems to have done the trick - thanks. could you explain it a bit , is the second argument feeding into the third argument (so that i get a string representation from ::text[])?